# Creating random matrix without one number

Tags: r, random

I want to generate a matrix of size n-1 x n such that the i-th column contains all number from 1 to n without containing i, i.e. the first column should contain all numbers from 2 to n, the second should contain 1,3,4,..., the third should contain 1,2,4,... and so on.
Any ideas would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We loop through the sequence of 'n', get the `sample` of the sequence except the looped number (`setdiff`)

```
sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) sample(setdiff(seq_len(n), i)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    2    3    1    3    2    2
#[2,]    5    1    5    6    1    5
#[3,]    6    4    6    2    3    4
#[4,]    3    5    4    1    4    1
#[5,]    4    6    2    5    6    3
```

It can be made a bit more faster if we use `vapply`

```
vapply(seq_len(n), function(i) sample(setdiff(seq_len(n), i)), numeric(n-1))
```

NOTE: The OP mentioned `random` matrix in the post

#### data

```
n <- 6
```

Comment: One more question: is there a way to add the missing i to each column so to make the matrix nxn? This, is, the last row should be 1 2 3 4 .... n.

Comment: @JosuéOrtega. You can use `rbind` i.e. `rbind(sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) sample(setdiff(seq_len(n), i))), seq_len(n))`

Answer (score 5):

Use `combn` (not really random though).

```
n <- 5
out <- combn(n:1, n - 1)
out
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    5    5    5    5    4
#[2,]    4    4    4    3    3
#[3,]    3    3    2    2    2
#[4,]    2    1    1    1    1
```

Shuffle each column if needed

```
set.seed(1)
apply(combn(n:1, n - 1), 2, sample)
```

---

If you are looking for efficiency, use the solution I posted ;)

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- 1000
set.seed(1)
benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  akrun = vapply(seq_len(n), function(i) sample(setdiff(seq_len(n), i)), numeric(n-1)),
  markus = apply(combn(n:1, n - 1), 2, sample),
  A_Stam = create_matrix(n),
  times = 30L
)
```

[image]

```
benchmark
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  akrun   64.32350   66.99177   73.61685   71.15608   78.79612  104.99161    30
# markus   51.65092   53.01034   59.80802   58.48310   64.76143   78.35348    30
# A_Stam 1331.52882 1379.70371 1470.31044 1407.89861 1548.28011 1896.22913    30
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
create_matrix <- function(n) {
  m <- c()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    new <- setdiff(1:n, i)
    m <- c(m, new)
  }
  matrix(m, ncol = n, byrow = FALSE)
}

create_matrix(4)

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    2    1    1    1
#> [2,]    3    3    2    2
#> [3,]    4    4    4    3
```

Comment: If you want the values to be arranged randomly, you could use `new <- sample(setdiff(1:n, i))`.